# access - update form only with button control

Tags: forms, ms-access

I saw some answeres here but none of them fitted to me.

I have a form with bounded inputs, which I want the user to be able to edit.
though, when the user changes the fields, and then close the form - even without clicking the "update" button - it changes the data in the database.

is there a way to verify that the data will be changed only when the "update" button is pressed?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

1) Define a global variable in the form "ButtonPressed" and set it to false when you enter the form or record (e.g. OnCurrent).

2) In Form_BeforeUpdate() put the following code:

```
If Not ButtonPressed Then Cancel = True
```

3) In Button_Click() put the following code:

```
ButtonPressed = True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

4) Reset the ButtonPressed after updating the form in Form_AfterUpdate()
The whole code should look like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim ButtonPressed As Boolean

Private Sub Button_Click()
    ButtonPressed = True
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    ButtonPressed = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not ButtonPressed Then Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    ButtonPressed = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Undo
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    If DataErr = 2169 Then
        Response = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Alexander Remesch works almost perfect - when I exit without clicking the save button, I get an error message from access which says that ms encountered error while trying to save, and if I am sure that I want to exit the form. - how do I disable this message?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I experimented a bit with `Form_Unload` (putting a `Me.Undo`in it) but found no solution except setting the `CloseButton` property of the form to false and implementing a seperate button for closing the form that does a `Me.Undo` before. I edited above code to include this event.

Comment: I found a way to pass through it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953949/preventing-close-buttons-from-saving-records-in-ms-access - see @salih0vicX answer.
thanks!

Comment: Great! I made another edit to show the complete code above.