# Required Fields Before Update in Conjunction with Close Button

Tags: vba, ms-access, userform

Novie VBA programmer here, looking for the ABC's direction.

I have 3 fields that I need to require in a form before the form is close.
I had previously require the fields within the Table; However, when I create a new contact to add to this Form I need to Requery the results of the added contact. When I Requery and the required fields are Required from the Table I reach a stuck, since I need to add the new contact but cannot Requery until the fields are filled (and I cannot do that until I have the right contact).

I know this is in the wrong place but this is the code I have thus far attached to my "Close" button.

```
Private Sub SaveCloseBtn_Click()

If Nz([PlaintiffName], "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Plaintiff Name is required.", vbExclamation, "Required Field"
        Cancel = True
End If
    If Nz([LawFirm], "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Law Firm is required.", vbExclamation, "Required Field"
            Cancel = True
                Me.[LawFirm].SetFocus
End If
    If [PlaintiffName] = True Then
        If [LawFirm] = True Then
            If MsgBox("You are about to exit this case. Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Warning!") = vbYes Then

        DoCmd.Close

    Else

        DoCmd.CancelEvent

End If
    
End Sub
```

I tried creating Required fields in "BeforeUpdate" but for whatever reason, it does not work in conjunction with the docmd.close form function.

Comment: This is the code that has been entered for "Before Update":

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If Nz([PlaintiffName], "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Plaintiff Name is required.", vbExclamation, "Required Field"
        Cancel = True
End If
    If Nz([LawFirm], "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Law Firm is required.", vbExclamation, "Required Field"
            Cancel = True
                Me.[LawFirm].SetFocus
End If
    If [PlaintiffName] = True Then
        If [LawFirm] = True Then
End If

End Sub

Comment: This is the code for my "Close" button:

Private Sub SaveCloseBtn_Click()

    If MsgBox("You are about to exit this case. Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Warning!") = vbYes Then

        DoCmd.Close

    Else

        DoCmd.CancelEvent

End If
    
End Sub

Comment: I need these two codes to work in tandem, and the Close button not to activate unless the required fields have been populated.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and put that code there. As you can see, code cannot be properly formatted in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing close buttons from saving records in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953949/preventing-close-buttons-from-saving-records-in-ms-access)